# A religious teacher slapped my son twice for refuting God, what should I do?

Tags: primary-schooler, school, manners

First, I am an atheist and so is my husband, and our 8 year old son is taught religion in a school since it is mandatory for all students, we didn't object because we thought that we could tell him about the "fallacies" later when he grows up to become a teenager.

But he didn't need us for that and during a class in which the teacher was explaining how "kind" and "merciful" God is, my son raised questions and then making the conclusion that God is not at all merciful, leading the teacher (who is extremely religious) to angrily go over to the seat of my son, grab him by the shoulders and slap him furiously TWICE.

The teacher then accused us of "degrading" his mind and that it is "not normal for such a young boy to naturally behave in such a way, unless he has been taught to do so", when we haven't done nothing. My son has never used a computer so he did not get the ideas from the internet, and he has no friends in the class as he's very introverted and usually extremely quiet. And I do understand that perhaps his words may have been inappropriate, but for the teacher to just abuse him like that is totally unacceptable.

We argued with the teacher since I was very angry, and the principal intervened to let it go and advised us to correctly teach him the Bible and to teach him some "manners as well". This ofcourse came to us as extremely offensive, why should I teach him the Bible? The school is entirely on the teacher's side, and I feel that the teacher will continue to misbehave with my son. And I think we should report him to the police for this. But...would it be right to do so? Are we just really making a big deal out of this? What if the teachers behave rudely or just don't give enough attention to my son after this, should I say something to them?

I must also stress that we cannot take him out from the school since we live and work in a very small town distanced away from the city, and there's only one elementary school here.

Comment: Can you please clarify where he developed his ideas, if not from his parents or the internet? (Those words are unlikely to be spoken by even a very insightful 8 year old child; unlikely to be repeated verbatim by the teacher, and unlikely to be reported back to you in this manner of dialogue. A bright 8 year old will know approximately 10,000 words.)

Comment: I'm confused. Were you in the room with him, or did the school provide a transcript after the fact? But, also - where did this happen? The cultural context is important, and the legal implications would vary from place to place.

Comment: If it's at all possible, move. I have a little knowledge of what small town culture is like, which is to say they tend to be extremely homogenous and unforgiving of people who don't fit in.  Because it's small, everyone will know you as "the atheists." For your son, it will make him very vulnerable to bullying, and it will be more difficult to make friends.  Because of the extremely homogenous culture, it will be extremely difficult to convince other adults of your position, as you saw when the principal did not really support you, as wrong as his actions are.

Comment: What country are you in? (Makes a difference to the legal position).

Comment: Without knowing your country (and therefore local laws on corporal punishment in school, etc.), it will be a challenge to get a good answer. Please **[edit]** to clarify that.

Comment: It doens't matter how the kid developed (itself, from you, others, a mix of all) the ideas or what level of language (simple language or bright language) was used. What matter is the behaviour of your son (did he speak in a fair way, no personal insults) and the teacher (did the teachter suppress other opionions by violence? did the teacher want to make your unreligious kids religious?).

Comment: @Erica - the question is clear - should I report this to the police? and are we making too big a deal of this? - please reopen this.

Comment: This needs an answer badly - I am a devout Christian, with 15 years as a missionary translating the Bible for minority languages.  I wish I could apologize enough to you.  What this teacher did is completely not acceptable, and criminal in every country I know of (almost every country in the world has accepted the UN definitions of child abuse and this falls squarely under that).  You might give the school one more chance to discipline this teacher and assure you that your child will be treated with respect.  But you'd be right to report this to the police right away.

Comment: If this school is a mission school, I encourage you to contact the head office of the mission, in your country, and report this.  Regardless of what the school does.  If this is a foreign mission, I also encourage you to report this to the headquarters of that mission in their country of origin.  I was in charge of child safety for my mission, and if this had happened in my watch, regardless of what the child said or did, I would have come down like a ton of bricks on that teacher, most likely I would have fired them and made an example of them.  Such treatment of children cannot be tolerated.

Comment: I'm going to guess you're not in the USA. That would result in the teacher being fired immediately and if the school is lucky they wouldn't be sued. If you have no choice but to send your kid to a school where they teach these things as fact then you should prepare them to expect people to be irrationally defensive about the subject and try not to offend their beliefs. Personally I'd move before allowing my kids to be raised in that kind of environment where a professor of christianity demonstrates the opposite of  their teachings.

Comment: @KaiQing Hitting children is still allowed in many US schools.Violence against the child in the home is allowed in every US state. Violence against the child in public school is allowed in about 19 US states. In 2011-2012 over 150,000 school children where hit in US schools. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/School_corporal_punishment_in_the_United_States

Answer (score 31):

I'm going to skip over the entire religious part of the question and answer what you should do about the much simpler part:

**If a teacher physically assaulted your son over a verbal debate, you should take legal steps. This person is unfit to be a teacher.**

You should talk to a lawyer.

Comment: Agreed; the teacher is unfit to be around children.

Comment: I've no idea what jurisdiction the OP is in, but since assault is a criminal offence in lots of countries, it may be better to make a complaint to the police.

Comment: Complaining to the police might also work (There's a good chance this is also what the lawyer will say you should do)

Comment: I cannot down vote however I disagree, If she turned into legal action then the school will not feel confertoble with them so the kid will not feel confertable in the school especially the principal didn't feel that hiting is wrong

Comment: The child very likely already does not feel comfortable in school. He was assaulted by a person in authority, who is probably twice his height and vastly stronger, while nobody intervened. I doubt he'll feel safe there from this point on.

Comment: @Moudiz - agree with Erik.  The child is already not comfortable, most likely full of fear and his education is in serious jeopardy, because there is no way this kid is going to trust those in authority at the school, and it seems unlikely they will treat the child with respect if they are not made to see their grievous error.  As a Christian myself, I cringe at this.  How can anyone who claims to follow Christ, who honored kids and demonstrated the utmost care and kindness towards children, behave like this.  Christ will have some words for this person.

Comment: Hitting children is still allowed in many US schools.Violence against the child in the home is allowed in every US state. Violence against the child in public school is allowed in about 19 US states. In 2011-2012 over 150,000 school children where hit in US schools

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/School_corporal_punishment_in_the_United_States